# Did Magata Shiki have a sister?

Tags: subete-ga-f-ni-naru

I was reviewing my [question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/29942/17758) about how the killer got on the roof and it suddenly struck me how weird the scene I posted in that question was.

Here it is again for reference:

[image: Picture from Episode 3: Magata returning from the roof]

In this scene, we see Yamane introducing Miki to her own aunt. We later find out that Miki was actually Dr. Magata. Did Dr. Magata really have a sister, or not? I ask because I find that it's weird that the Aunt would not know her niece, or at least know if her brother/sister had children. It also seems weird that they would not have met. I remember that while Dr. Magata was acting as Miki she told Professor Saikawa that she was raised in America, away from Dr. Magata. However, even that sounds strange as Dr. Magata's parents were not separated.

On the other hand, it seems ever more odd if she *didn't* have a sister, because that would mean the aunt should have known right away that Miki was an imposter.

Comment: This bugs me too. The most plausible explanation I've seen is that 1.) Shiki never had a sister; 2.) Shiki's aunt didn't comment on this because she was privy to Shiki's scheme. I've seen various motives proposed for her being willing to go along with Shiki's scheme, such as her being unhappy with her husband (Shiki's uncle) for the whole affair thing and being okay with Shiki killing him.

Comment: In the drama cd stated that shiki's parents were going to divorce, but after the island lab finished. So the celebration is the last day for them as a family.

Comment: This wasn't so odd after activating my suspension of disbelief to allow for me to overlook that she got a child while isolated from everyone and nobody noticing for 15 years.